# Let $~a\lt b\lt c\lt d$，proof that if $f$ is a convex function both in $[a,c]$ and $[b,d]$, $f$ is convex in $[a,d]$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a problem from mathematical analysis.

It is clear that we only need to discuss the the problem when $x_1$, $x_2$ are located in $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ respectively.

I have tried mark $x_0$ in $[b,c]$ as I think this may help me use the definition of convex function.

(I am sorry that my English is poor, thank you very much)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove the real value function $f$ is convex on $[a,d]$ if $f$ is convex on both $[a,c]$ and $[b,d]$? ($a<b<c<d$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880075/how-to-prove-the-real-value-function-f-is-convex-on-a-d-if-f-is-convex-o)